# Why is this person shocked?

Tags: safety

[image]

The voltage over the person is 250V. Why does he receive a shock? Doesn't the earth have a very big resistance so the current will be very small?

Comment: they get shocked because electricity is so awesome!

#pun4fun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The voltage over the person is 250V. Why does he receive a shock? Doesn't the earth have a very big resistance so the current will be very small?

This is exactly the reason. The resistance of the person is less than the resistance of the earth between his feet, so most of the current resulting from this voltage is flowing through him. Equivalent circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAMbz6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: So when you are touching the earth, you are forming a parallel circuit and not a circuit in series?

Comment: Parallel to the section of the earth between the feet, yes. It would be in series if the person holding the cable by hand and keeping his feet together (and in this case the person will be literally fried in a moment..).

Comment: What's the difference between this case or a bird standing on a wire and doesn't get shock?

Comment: Distance between the legs and the resistance of the wire versus the resistance of the ground.

Answer (score 2):

They are shocked because the resistance of the ground for the distance between their feet is higher than (or comparable to) the resistance through their body. The earth does have high resistance, but there is also a few thousand volts there.

This is the same reason that cows and sheep are more likely to be killed by a lightning strike if they are standing perpendicular to the ground current flow.

If you're ever in a lightning storm in an open field or in the situation depicted above, just stand with your feet very close together. It might save your life.

Comment: *If you're ever in a lightning storm in an open field or in the situation depicted above, just stand with your feet very close together. It might save your life.*  How about skipping on one foot?

Comment: @Fennekin Sure, that could work. However, as you have no idea when lightning will strike, you might just be wasting a lot of energy. You also risk tripping yourself.

Comment: What's the highest point in an open field where you're standing alone?  Answer: your head.  So lying down flat on the ground might just also save your life? /  But I'm also a bit skeptical to my own statement: the length of the field is two-three orders of magnitude longer than you, so the chances of lightning strikes using you as a shorter path to ground are slim? And the soil might not be equally conductive, so there might be a hotspot for lightning strikes?

Comment: @OskarSkog Your head being the highest point is only important if the voltage gradient is perfectly perpendicular to the going over the entire field.

Answer (score 1):

Humans also have a very big resistance, but likely some less than the ground, so the body becomes a current path.